# Does the WinApi ever validate UTF-16?

Tags: winapi, utf-16

The Windows documentation makes repeated reference to both UNICODE and UTF-16. I know this is a lie for the [file system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) (i.e. it accepts any sequence of `wchar_t`) and [other documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/surrogates-and-supplementary-characters) suggests that invalid UTF-16 is merely "undefined. So I'm confused. Can I assume non filesystem APIs will return valid UTF-16? Or should I assume it wont?

**Edit:** As it's causing some confusion I'll explain a few terms

---

### UTF-16

UTF-16 is defined in the [Unicode specification (pdf)](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/UnicodeStandard-11.0.pdf). The [FAQ](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-7) makes clear what is and isn't well formed UTF-16:

> **Are there any 16-bit values that are invalid?**
>
> Unpaired surrogates are invalid in UTFs. These include any value in the range D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub> not followed by a value in the range DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub>, or any value in the range DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub> not preceded by a value in the range D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub>.
>
> **What about noncharacters? Are they invalid?**
>
> Not at all. Noncharacters are valid in UTFs and must be properly converted. For more details on the definition and use of noncharacters, as well as their correct representation in each UTF, see the [Noncharacters FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#noncharacters).

So the only restriction is that a leading surrogate must be followed by a trailing surrogate (aka a surrogate pair). All other `wchar_t` (16 bit) values should be accepted as is.

---

### UCS-2

As mentioned in Ben Voigt's answer. This is a now obsolete encoding that allowed any `wchar_t` values. As it doesn't have the same restrictions as UTF-16, a subset of UCS-2 strings are invalid UTF-16.

Comment: "non filesystem APIs", do you mean **every other API on earth**? I'm thinking this question might just be a tad too broad.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Every other Windows `W` API. Yes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no actual validation done anywhere. Validation might be done when reading text from disk, ie. reading a text file and interpreting it as UTF-8 in order to generate unicode code points, but I wouldn't bet on this catching everything.

Comment: Additionally, what kind of validation are we talking about here? That every code point is a valid and known code point? That wouldn't be forward compatible as new code points are added regularly, just look at the recent years additions of emojis, like the  which was added in 2015.

Comment: Valid UTF-16 encompasses code points that haven't be defined yet. So valid UTF-16 is a sequence of any 16 bit integers, except that a trailing surrogate must follow a leading surrogate and vice versa.

Comment: @las: `WideCharToMultiByte` will inevitably have to do UTF-16 validation. This question talks about the filesystem API, as the underlying filesystem (predominantly NTFS) doesn't care about UTF-16. It will be happy to name files using any sequence of 16-bit numbers other than zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows wide characters are arbitrary 16-bit numbers (formerly called "UCS-2", before the Unicode Standard Consortium purged that notation).  So you cannot assume that it will be a valid UTF-16 sequence.  (`MultiByteToWideChar` is a notable exception that does return only UTF-16)

Decoding as UTF-16 only makes sense if the program that generated the string used a UTF-16 convention, but there's no guarantee about that just as there's no guarantee that 8-bit characters contain UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a source? The Windows documentation strongly implies the `W` functions (outside of file system paths) all use utf-16. For example [LPCWSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230352.aspx) and [Unicode character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230275.aspx#gt_fd33af2e-e1ce-4f8e-a706-f9fb8123f9b0)

Comment: @ChrisD: Windows Unicode support existed from before there was such a thing as UTF.  The only way to introduce conditions that the data has to be valid UTF-16 would be to break backward compatibility, which hasn't been done.  APIs introduced in XP and later wouldn't have that concern, but they have to interoperate with the existing APIs, so there you go.  For best results, apply Postel's Law.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think Windows is UTF-16 these days. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081(v=vs.85).aspx makes it pretty clear.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Nowhere does it say that strings returned from APIs are guaranteed to be valid UTF-16.  So you're left wondering whether it doesn't say UCS-2 because it really is UTF-16, or it doesn't say UCS-2 because of a political decision to not use that term anymore.  When you think about backward compatibility, though, there isn't that much to wonder about.  Also that page says "New Windows applications should use UTF-16", which is basically an admission that old software uses UCS-2 wide characters, and if you exchange data with it in any way, you can see non-UTF-16 too.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well the docs are quite explicit about UTF-16 being supported, and it has been this way since Windows 2000 afaik. Prior to Windows 2000, the API didn't support surrogate pairs. Now it does. But the range U+D800 to U+DFFF are not valid Unicode characters except as part of a surrogate pair, so even when the API only supported UCS-2 these characters should never have been used meaningfully.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: But people have been using `wchar_t[]` for binary storage the whole time, especially via `BSTR` which is length-prefixed.

Comment: The console API is also legacy UCS-2. It renders any surrogate code using the current font's default glyph (e.g. an empty rectangle), regardless of whether it's a valid UTF-16 surrogate pair. Strings read from the console's input buffer and screen buffer(s) may not be valid UTF-16, in which case, for example, encoding to UTF-8 via `WideCharToMultiByte` may either fail or substitute U+FFFD, depending on whether the `WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag is used.

Comment: Sorry, but @JonathanPotter is right here: Windows uses UTF-16 since Windows 2000 (i.e. for almost 2 decades). `WideCharToMultiByte` will perform UTF-16 validation, and calling `MultiByteToWideChar` will inevitably return UTF16 that isn't UCS-2. Likewise, DirectWrite will render UTF-16 glyphs. The console subsystem is really the only part in Windows, that's not UTF-16 aware by default.

Comment: @IInspectable: What about messages to windows with a Unicode window procedure?  Clipboard storage?  OLE streams?  RPC marshalling?  SAM account names?  Glyph display is a tiny, tiny part of string handling in Win32.

Comment: Most of those API's don't care about their payload: They'll just forward it. There would be no difference between UCS-2 and UTF-16 API's. They simply don't care. The only API's that do care are those 'leaf' API's, that need to interpret the input. That's pretty much only rendering and conversion.

Comment: @IInspectable: Exactly.  When using any API that doesn't care about its payload, you can't rely on any guarantee of UTF-16 from the OS.  You only get what guarantee the data source gives.  Which is what my answer says.

Comment: @IInspectable: Also note that the question asks about strings returned from APIs, not inputs.  So the rendering API isn't even relevant.

Comment: No, that's not what your answer implies. It says, that the data **is** UCS-2. Which is just as wrong. It is, whatever the caller passed. If you insist, that you cannot rely on UTF-16, then really, you cannot claim that UCS-2 were guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, but `MultiByteToWideChar` is guaranteed to return UTF-16. And has done so for almost 2 decades.

Comment: @IInspectable: UCS-2 is guaranteed just by the size of the data type.  But I edited, is that better?

Comment: Looks better. I don't know enough about UCS-2 to make the call, whether all UCS-2 encoded strings are valid UTF-16 strings (i.e. all UTF-16 surrogate leads are invalid UCS-2 code units). If that is the case, then the distinction really is an academic exercise, without much practical relevance.

Comment: @IInspectable The distinction is that Windows functions can potentially return a series of 16 bit integers that are not valid UTF-16. Which answers my question, no?

Comment: @chr: That's what my previous comment was trying to verify. If UCS-2 is always valid UTF-16, then you need not make that distinction in your code. Simply write your UTF-16 aware code, and be done with it. Regardless of that, Stack Overflow strives for canonical Q&A's. This question is close, and Ben Voigt being a member capable of writing up the most succinct of answers you could hope for, I'm just trying to help steer this Q&A towards the right direction (according to my personal opinion).

Comment: @IInspectable: There are no invalid UCS-2 code units, only that some code values have no associated meaning, and others have special meaning (other than representing a glyph).  UTF-16 does make some code values invalid, but more importantly it restricts the sequence in which surrogates may appear.  So many sequences which are legal (although they may lack semantic meaning) in UCS-2 are illegal in UTF-16.